# Issue with accessing multiple files with same name from different folder in Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

Question related to Robot Framework

I have 3 folders in a Project inside Pycharm: A, B and C

Inside folder A there is Common.robot file with keywords `Suite Setup` and `User Info`.
Inside folder B there is Common.robot file with keyword `Suite Setup`.
I need to access `Common.User Info` in folder A and `Common.Suite Setup` in folder B from the folder C.

In resource I put

```
*** Settings ***
Resource            ../A/Common.robot
Resource            ../B/Common.robot

Suite Setup         Common.Suitesetup
```

I am unable to execute and getting error as below

> Parent suite setup failed:
> Multiple keywords with name 'Common.Suite Setup' found:
> Common.Suite Setup 
> Common.Suite Setup

Kindly advise how to chose specific suite setup from folder C as I have 2 Common.robot files

Thanks

Comment: When importing _libraries_ the framework allowsa custom prefix with the `WITH NAME` argument for precisely this situation, but I'm not sure it is supported for resource files. It's worth the try, though.

Answer (score 0):

Robot Framework supports calling keywords directly with variables. This does **not** allow you to import a keyword with same name twice over, but it does enable you to have same test run different setup in different environments or to alter the test flow otherwise.

I use this setup for running same set of tests in multiple different environments and because all of the environments are slightly different, I need to have a different setup for each of them. You can consider the below simplified example:

```
# In SetupKeywords.robot

*** Keywords ***
Suite Setup A
    # do stuff

Suite Setup B
    # do stuff
```

```
# In TestSuite.robot

*** Settings ***
Resource    .\\SetupKeywords.robot

Suite Setup    Suite Setup ${ENV}

*** Test Cases ***
Test Case 1
    # do stuff
```

Now when running any test, simply add `-v ENV:B` to the Robot launch options and you will run the test with `Suite Setup B`. The test itself will remain the same and there's no need for conflicting keyword names in the setup files.

So to reiterate, when launching the robot, your CMD command would look like this:

`robot -v ENV:A .\Path\to\TestSuites`

Adding of course any other parameters you are using.

Adjusted to your case you would need to rename your `SuiteSetup` keyword to a unique name and then add the variable to the robot call. In case you'll need more robust system, I'd encourage you to check the [Resource and Variable Files](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#resource-and-variable-files) section in Robot Framework User Guide.